# Python: lst[(lst.index("search-term"))] = article in function body vs. return

Tags: python, function, return-value

Python 3.7:

Why does the following code work (focus on the function):

```
shelf = ["Zaubersäge", "leer", "Wunderkekse", "Trickarten", "leer"]

def add_shelf(article):
    shelf[(shelf.index("leer"))] = article
    return

add_shelf("Rubik's Cube")
print(shelf)
```

but not this one:

```
shelf = ["Zaubersäge", "leer", "Wunderkekse", "Trickarten", "leer"]

def add_shelf(article):
    return (shelf[(shelf.index("leer"))] = article)

add_shelf("Rubik's Cube")
print(shelf)
```

Comment: Thanks toolic. I found out that my version of Python on Azure does not like parenthsis around the statement like so: (shelf[(shelf.index("leer"))] = article). It runs without enclosing parenthesis if part of the function body. But it does not run w/o parenthis if in the return statement. So I enclosed it and it does not work. Only after your comment I double checked and found out my copy-and-paste error. But the problem occurs. I cannot shortcut the statement shelf[(shelf.index("leer"))] = article as part of the return-statement like so: „return shelf[(shelf.index("leer"))] = article.“ Thanks.

Comment: An equals sign (assignment statement) in a return statement is invalid. What were you expecting to happen? BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign a value within a `return` statement. For example, `return foo = 1` is invalid. I think in general you can't put a statement in a statement, but that's beside the point.

What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: The idea is to replace the first occurance of the element “leer” with a value received into the function. I am not about getting better ideas like list comprehension etc. I found out that Python does not like the term in brackets independent if in a function body or in the return statement: (shelf[(shelf.index("leer"))] = article). I just noticed this behavour first in the return statement since i thought this makes the 1-liner-working. But it does not.

Comment: Gotcha. If you need to make the function a one-liner, just get rid of the `return` statement, cause functions return implicitly in Python.

Comment: BTW apparently "leer" means "empty" in German, so I'd recommend using `None` in the list instead, since it's purpose-built to be a sentinel value. There's no difference in functionality, but it's clearer and would give you memory savings for big lists.